# some of the byte array not copied to targeted file c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, arrays

The code below retrieves a byte array from an online API and creates and opens a file. And it copies the byte array to the file.

But some of the bytes are not copied, I've checked this problem by analyzing the byte array length and targeted file size after the copy operation using an if condition.

```
filename = fn + img[i].name.Replace(@"/", "-");
var stream = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(
    new Uri(img[i].url.Replace("//", "http://")));
var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(
    filename + ".jpg", 
    CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
var targetstream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
await targetstream.AsStreamForWrite().WriteAsync(stream, 0, stream.Length);
string a = Convert.ToString(targetstream.Size);
string b = Convert.ToString(stream.Length);
if (a == b)
{
    tiles t = new tiles();
    t.TileName = img[i].title;
    t.ImgUri = file.Path;
    this.tileList.Items.Add(t);
}
```

Any solutions to copying all of the byte array to the file?

Comment: Do you remember to close the file?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlson i ve tried stream close, dispose but still im getting some files not copied

Comment: You should always close the files you use. When you say "some files not copied", do you mean that the entire file is missing in the target directory, or that the file is there, just not containing the right number of bytes?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlson yes, just not containing the right number of bytes

Comment: Well, other than making sure to close all your files (which you're not doing in the example code in the question), I don't know what else to say.

Comment: Do you have access to the api side code? It might be possible that for example a flush command is needed there.

Comment: It is impossible to emphasize too strongly the advice Lasse is providing: the code you posted does not close the file, but you _must_ close the file to ensure all the bytes have been written and that it's accessible for use by other code. When you done writing to a file, close it!